# Could not be able to print Mysqli query result in php

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to print result of a Mysqli query, But when I try to do as following way, It does not return any values or error. The code does not go through the while loop. What would be the wrong with my code, Please help me!

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "domains");
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
        exit();
    }
    $part = explode(".", $str);
    $part1 = $part[0];
    $part2 = $part[1];

    $sql = "SELECT
            DomainCategory.Name
        FROM
            DomainName_Client,
            DomainNameType,
            DomainCategory,
            OrderDomain_Client
        WHERE
            DomainName_Client.Name = '$part1'
        AND DomainNameType.Name = '$part2'
        AND DomainName_Client.TypeID = DomainNameType.ID
        AND DomainCategory.ID = DomainName_Client.DomainCategoryID
        AND OrderDomain_Client.DomainNameID = DomainName_Client.ID";

    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

    if (!$result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
        die('There was an error running the query ' . $mysqli->error . ']');
    }
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo 'Total results: ' . $result->num_rows;
    }
?>
```

Comment: have you tried with your query in mysql ? echo $sql; and try it in phpmyadmin..

Comment: Why you are using while loop?

Comment: if this code doesn't print anything then your query returned no rows. as simple as that.

Comment: also don't run `$mysqli->query($sql)` twice.unnecessary

Comment: your SQL query should be rewritten to use JOINs.

Comment: You want to be [using MySQL prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) not query,

Comment: @Martin can you demonstrate us you brand new shiny OOP approach without while loop please?

Comment: Chonchol was asking why using the while loop, and it is left over from the older style of *MySQL_* array output. Object output can be done with a while loop but it's a bit of a throwback. @YourCommonSense

Comment: @Martin so I take it as there is another, an OOP-way, without a while loop. Can you show it please?

Comment: @YourCommonSense `mysqli_fetch_all` will do it but only works with the `mysqlnd` driver. I was under an impression that there was a more *call-and-dump* way of outputting full result sets, but this seems not to be.

Comment: @Martin so, am I getting it right that using `foreach` is  OOP-way and `while` is procedural way? thank you for the insight.

Comment: @YourCommonSense no, I made no mention of foreach. I was under an impression there was a method for calling and dumping larger groups of data than simply line by line while calls. You've caused me to look into the code more deeply and I find that there is no practical alternative way of outputting MySQL data. While the `while` output syntax is very old, it is still the only practical way of getting muti-row data output from a MySQL query.

Comment: @Martin but you can use foreach over mysqli_fetch_all() as you mentioned, which technically could be called an alternative. but I see not it was just a confusion on oop part. Cheers :)

Comment: @YourCommonSense it's been worth my while digging in, better understanding (and correcting) my assumptions.

Comment: ( It does surprise me there are no other -for example JSON-format - outputs for MySQL queries, at least on MySQLi )

Answer (score 1):

First you check the number of results returning in the sql query using the following code and after that you print it using while or for loop.

```
echo $result->num_rows;
```